# Head loss from rectangular slot orifice flowing up?

Tags: hydraulics

For sizing purposes I'm trying to calculate head loss for a level spreader outlet for water, where the water is being supplied from below by pressure. It's essentially a reverse slot drain—instead of water flowing down the slot and leaving, it's entering from below and leaving up through the top of the slot. There's no outlet pipe; everything leaves through the slot for the purposes of this calculation. Here's a sketch showing two views of it (I left off the inlet pipe):

[image: two views of slot weir showing path of water and relevant dimensions]

Once the water leaves the slot, vertically, I know it can be modeled as weir flow, so I can calculate the height it would have to reach for a given flow rate for a sharp rectangular weir of its length. From that I know I need at least enough head/water height to reach that height above the slot: $D_{pipe} + H_{slot} + H_{weir}$.

**My question is,** how do I model the friction losses from the slot itself? I imagine the width of the slot to be significant, at least for small enough widths. I found a rectangular submerged orifice equation from [this site](http://irrigation.wsu.edu/Content/Calculators/Water-Measurements/Rectangular-Submerged-Orifices.php) (using cfs & square feet):

> $Q = 0.61A \cdot \sqrt{64.4 \cdot H} $

and there are definite similarities: the top of the slot in my problem is also a rectangular opening that, once enough water is flowing, will have water on all sides. However, it's turned 90 degrees, so I feel that the above equation might not be appropriate. I imagine the equation above takes into consideration the need for additional head to drive enough horizontal flow, which might be different from the vertical flow in the slot I'm considering.

What's an appropriate way to calculate the head loss from the slot opening itself?